# PHP: Two same date statements but day of the week is wrong in one of them

Tags: php

I've written this code:

```
if(!is_null($customDate)){
    $referenceDate = strtotime($customDate);
    $toDay = date("N", $referenceDate);
    echo("/".$referenceDate."/".$toDay."/");
}
else{
    $referenceDate = strtotime(date("d:m:y"));
    $toDay = date("N");
    echo("/".$referenceDate."/".$toDay."/");
}
```

if I supply $customDate like:

function_name("24:07:17");

it prints out this:

> /1500941237/2/

A datestamp (I assume) and 2 as day of week - Tuesday.

If I don't supply $customDate and call function as:

function_name();

I get this:

> /1500941237/1/

Which is again - datestamp (I assume) and 1 for day of Week - Monday.

The second one is correct, it's 24th and it's Monday.

I am pretty new to PHP so I am almost 100% sure there is some small nuance in regards to operations with dates I am doing but I am not sure what it is.

How can two identical datestamps produce difference day of week?

Running it on WAMP server on Windows 10 with default config.

Full function:

```
function nextDate($customDate=null){

    $referenceDate;
    $toDay;


    if(!is_null($customDate)){
        $referenceDate = strtotime($customDate);
        $toDay = date("N", $referenceDate);
        echo("/".$referenceDate."/".$toDay."/");
    }
    else{
        $referenceDate = strtotime(date("d:m:y"));
        $toDay = date("N");
        echo("/".$referenceDate."/".$toDay."/");
    }

}
```

> nextDate("24:07:17"); --> gives wrong result, it says 24th is Tuesday.
>
> nextDate(); --> gives correct result, it says 24th is Monday.

Comment: Can you show us the code handling the date afterwards?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton there is no afterwards date handling, I simply call nextDate() from outside of function.

Comment: I have run your code online editor and I have not seen any issue there is same result showing in both conditions . http://www.writephponline.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's because `24:07:17` is not valid  date format, PHP thinks it's a time so "today 24:07:17"

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("24:07:17"));
// outputs 2017-07-25 00:07:17
```

use valid date format or convert it to something `strtotime` will understand correctly:

```
list($d,$m,$y) = explode(":", "24:07:17");
$referenceDate = strtotime("20{$y}-{$m}-{$d}");
```

Comment: So it's a delimiter ":" problem or Day | Month | Year sequence?

Comment: @iAmTheGuy96 both. `date("Y-m-d", strtotime("01-03-17"));` is march 2001. we use Y-M-D in computers for number of reasons https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: Thank You, that explains it now. 

It works perfectly now.  Didn't know there is such a big difference between D:M:Y and Y-m-d